# How to make the first 2 values as key and next as values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to read a file and convert the 1st 2 values of each row as key and the next 2 as values

file_name.txt

```
    a b 1 2
    d e 2 3
    a c 4 6
```

I want to create a dictionary like this

```
 d={'a-b' :(1,2)},'d-e':(2,3)},'a-c':(4,6)}}
```

I converted the file into a list with each row being an element of the list:

```
  v_list=['a b 1 2','d e 2 3','a c 4 6']
```

I can also convert the file into a list with each value in each row as an element:

```
 v_list=['a','b','1','2','d','e','2','3','a',c','4','6']
```

But I am not getting proper reference to convert this list into a nested dictionary with values a tuple.
Can someone please suggest me how to go about it.

Comment: your dict is not valid one , because key `a` cannot be duplicated in dict

Comment: why duplicate keys? You cannot repeat keys.

Comment: 1st and 2nd column makes my entry unique.eg. a-b ,d-e and a-c are the unique keys

Comment: your keys are just `a,d` not a-b or d-e. b,e,c all these are the keys of the dicts that are the values of main dict.

Comment: Exactly. There's no concept of a combined key for a nested dict. In your example, 'a' is one of the keys for the top level dict, so you cannot have another entry with 'a' key.

Comment: I made a changed in the key,can this be achieved to make it unique?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is in the format you provided, you could try something like this:

```
nested = dict()
with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        tokens = line.strip().split()
        if (nested.get(tokens[0], 0) == 0):
            nested[tokens[0]] = dict()
        nested[tokens[0]][tokens[1]] = (tokens[2], tokens[3])

print(nested)
# prints:
# {'a': {'b': ('1', '2'), 'c': ('4', '6')}, 'd': {'e': ('2', '3')}}
```

As someone pointed out in comments, a dict can not have duplicate keys. This code will add the new value to existing key's dict.

Comment: prefer refer to my recent comment for unique key requirement.1st and 2nd column makes my entry unique.eg. a-b ,d-e and a-c are the unique keys

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read it as DataFrame, you can use pandas apply function and then convert series to dictionary. Please bear in mind, dictionary can't have duplicate keys as you have put in example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['a', 'd', 'a'], 'col2':['b', 'e', 'c'], 'col3' : [1,2,4], 'col4': [2,3,6]})
def createdict(x):
    dict2 ={}
    dict2[x['col2']] = (x['col3'], x['col4'])
    return dict2

df['dictcol'] = df.apply(createdict, axis=1)
df = df.set_index('col1')
df['dictcol'].to_dict()
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd column makes my entry unique.eg. a-b ,d-e and a-c are the unique keys

Answer (score 0):

You're example dictionary is invalid. Keys may only appear once. That is one of the key characteristics of dictionaries. That said, assuming you care about order, the following solution would work.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    d = OrderedDict()
    with open("./file_name.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            vals = line.split()
            d.setdefault(vals[0], {vals[1]: (vals[2], vals[3])})
print(d)
# OrderedDict([('a', {'b': ('1', '2')}), ('d', {'e': ('2', '3')})])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try with your first list :

```
v_list = ['a b 1 2', 'd e 2 3', 'a c 4 6']
d = {}
for i in v_list:
    st = i.replace(" ", "")
    d[st[0]+"-"+st[1]] = (st[2], st[3])
print(d)
```

As you cannot have duplicate keys in a dict you can try is to group values having same key, like in another dict or in a list

Here the o/p will be look like :

```
{'d-e': ('2', '3'), 'a-b': ('1', '2'), 'a-c': ('4', '6')}
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd column makes my entry unique.eg. a-b ,d-e and a-c are the unique keys

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your require output is {'a-b': ('1', '2'), 'd-e': ('2', '3'), 'a-c': ('4', '6')}

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
d = {}
for i in f.readlines():
    splt = i.split(" ")
    d[splt[0] + "-" + splt[1]] = (splt[2], splt[3])

print(d)
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd column makes my entry unique.eg. a-b ,d-e and a-c are the unique keys

Comment: The dictionary you want has a two times. Your desired output doesn't match with the keys  a-b ,d-e and a-c

Comment: My main objective is to make a-b ,d-e,a-c  a unique key.I edited  the output accordingly

Comment: see the new code. Your expected data is not in correct format. I've changed the code as per my assumption